# Accessing Visual FoxPro COM server from VB 6.0

Tags: com, visual-foxpro

The problem is related to the usage of VFP COM server from Visual basic 6.0 (SP 6).

Code (relevant)

```
Private moVFPServer As f_vfpsvr.VFPServer
```

In the Sub:

```
Dim oRec As f_vfpsvr.VFPRecord 
Set oRec = moVFPServer.NewRecord("LoanMstr")    
With oRec    
  .SetField "ssn", sSSN    
  .SetField "awdyr", sAwardYear    
  .SetField "tran_date", Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")    
  .Commit    
End With
```

Method "NewRecord" from moVFPServer returns an object which represents a new, empty record in the VFP table "LoanMstr".

Code follows to populate properties/fields and save data.

All this works if VFP COM server is built using VFP 8.0 and **does not work when built using VFP 9.0**.

Specifically, VB application errors out at the line of code:

```
Set oRec = moVFPServer.NewRecord("StdMstr")
```

COM server throws exception: automation error -2147417851.

This is happening on the same machine.

Comment: Does the COM object work when called from VFP 9?

Comment: -2147417851 = 0x80010105 = "The server threw an exception".  Your foxpro code crashed.

Comment: Tamar, I checked and it does not work in VFP development environment on VFP 8 or VFP 9.

Comment: Hans, exactly it crashed. The point is that code is executed by methods in COM server and it crashes exactly at the time when object is returned to the calling VB program.

Comment: BTW, method NewRecord in VFPServer calls another method which in turn instantiates object based on class VFPRecord located in the same DLL. If anybody would like to know how exactly method NewRecord works I will email the program containing classes. It is quite short and clean.

Comment: What if you instantiate NOT as a COM object in VFP? That is, just use CREATEOBJECT("VFPServer"). Then does it work? Try debugging within VFP until it works that way, and then try it as a COM object again.

Comment: Tamar, Thank you for you suggestion. Both objects: VFPServer and VFPRecordZ work as expected when directly instantiated from classes included in PRG. Since one of methods of VFPServer instantiates object based on VFPRecord (loRec  = CREATEOBJECT( 'f_vfpsvr.VFPRecord' )) I have to to some changes to test both of them working together. I will let know about results.

Answer (score 1):

VFP built COM objects can behave a little oddly at times, especially when it comes to trickling errors back up the stack.

But it seems very strange that this manifests only when built in VFP9.  I believe there WERE some breaking changes in database stuff between 8 and 9 some possibly you've hit one of them?

Do you have an ERROR function in the VFP code?  If not, try setting some error properties in that and interrogating them in VB when you get the error?

Ie, we have something like

```
FUNCTION ERROR(nError, cMethod, nLine)
    THIS.cErrDesc = "Error Number: " + TRANSFORM(nError) + CRLF + "Message: " + MESSAGE() + CRLF  + "Method: " + cMethod + CRLF  + "Line #: " + TRANSFORM(nLine)

    COMRETURNERROR(cMethod, THIS.cErrDesc)

ENDFUNC
```

Comment: I will try to implement ERROR function. I used log to trace a point in the program (COM server) where crash occurs. Actually all lines of code in the COM server method are executed correctly until the point when object is returned to the calling program.

Comment: @Paul, without knowing the result record structure, I would then consider looking at the data types being returned.  Do you have any General, Memo, Currency, or other columns that MIGHT be an issue from VFP8 and 9, if so, try to remove them either one TYPE at time, or all of them and gradually add columns to the returned set.  Simplest test, try to just return your object of a single column as char or int.  If THAT crashes, then it won't matter what the others are.

Comment: Thanks DRapp for the idea. Actually all fields are string or date types.